# How to add a directory not on C:\ to the PATH variable

Tags: windows-xp, path

I have recently installed Python in D:\Python32 and added that directory to my PATH variable, but it doesn't seem to work.  Does PATH only work with C:\ ?

OS is Win XP Pro 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it works on all disks. D: should be no problem. The most likely explanation is a typo somewhere.

Comment: I thought so... I went back and looked and I had a space in front of the preceding semi-colon:
[more stuff not shown];C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin; D:\Python32;
changed to -> [...];C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;D:\Python32;
  I removed this and now it works.  Silly me